# Why can't I see local variables in debugger, C# UWP VS2017?

Tags: c#, debugging, uwp, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to debug an app built using Xamarin forms and is running on windows for now in C#, but I am having problems debugging even simple things, since the local variables in methods are not accessible to debugger.  I even created a simple test below, and if I put breakpoint on output line, "hello" will be output, but in watch window it says test is not defined in context.  This is a simple example, but same thing exists in other methods.  I wonder if it has to do with method being async?  Is there an option I need to enable?

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    string test = "hello";
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(test);  // If I put breakpoint here, I can't see 'test'.
}
```

Comment: Not specific to 2017, but I have had issues with this when "Compile with .Net Native Tool Chain" is checked in Build tab of application properties and running in debug configuration.

Comment: @MarkW I can't seem to find Compile with .net Native Tool Chain inside of the build tab..?

Comment: @MarkW looking at my build settings I already have "Compile with .Net Native toolchain" unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your issue in Xamarin.Forms version 2.2.0.45. You could try to update Xamarin.Forms to the latest version. Right click the `solution`-> Manager NuGet Package for Solution -> click the Updates button on the NuGet Package Manager tab -> check all client project updating to laset version just like the following screen shot
[image]

As for the asynchronous method you use, you could use the `await` keyword in the method.

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    string test = "hello";
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(test);
});
```

If you have not used the await keyword ,the method will be invoked synchronously. And the statement will also be executed in the method.

Comment: So 2 things, I am already using 2.3.3.193 of Xamarin Forms.  Also the reason I show the example of Onstart as async is because in the full version I am calling an async method using await.  Note when I look up in the call stack it seems that things look normal until I get in the async OnStart method.